# how to solve maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object (Dice game)

Tags: python

mini dice game, roll 5 dice, if that is no repeated number will reroll till there is repeated number.

it crush till to due RecursionError after a few roll, i have no idea what is going on

```
import random

def roll():
  roll1 = random.randint(1,6)
  roll2 = random.randint(1,6)
  roll3 = random.randint(1,6)
  roll4 = random.randint(1,6)
  roll5 = random.randint(1,6)
  

  result = [roll1,roll2,roll3,roll4,roll5]
  
  result.sort()

  def check():
    while result == [1,2,3,4,5] or result == [2,3,4,5,6] or result == [1,3,4,5,6] or result == [1,2,4,5,6] or result == [1,2,3,5,6] or result == [1,2,3,4,6]:
      roll()
    else:
      print(result)
     
  check()

roll()
```

Comment: Why use `while` instead of `if`? The `result` doesn't change. So, if once `result` becomes one of the values in the condition it will loop endlessly

Comment: i try using if, but some time will not reroll

Comment: @IssacChew, did you use `if` with same condition?

Comment: No reproduction in my trials, although it's hypothetically possible. This rerolls until there are no repeats. It's a pretty rare chance for a single reroll, much less recursion limit. Even so, there's no need to make it recursive when you could have another function handle reroll.

Comment: Don't use recursion, to begin with.

Comment: @fam that's really not a good solution to the problem

Comment: @kuro i use `if result == [1,2,3,4,5]:
  roll()
elif result == [1,2,3,4,6]:
  roll():` and so on but it still print non repeated number

Comment: @KennyOstrom it roll non stop even it is repeated number. https://replit.com/@Isaac-ChewChew/dice-liar#main.py feel free to test it out

Comment: @IsaacChew, can you create share the code with `if`?

Comment: @kuro i have add in the code, with `if` it still print out non repeated number  https://replit.com/@Isaac-ChewChew/dice-liar#main.py

Comment: @IsaacChew, I am not getting non repeated number after replacing `while` with `if`

Comment: @kuro thanks i guess i must have overlook or something, it solve

Comment: @Isaac Chew that's different code. I ran the code posted here.